# How to translate urls in Gatsby.js with i18next

Tags: localization, gatsby, i18next, intl

I try to make my gatsby page multilingual.
I am using gatsby-plugin-react-i18next, i18next and react-i18next like in documentation.

i18n adds language prefix but page url is still the same. How i can translate friendly url?
i have: domain/es/hello-world
but i want: domain/es/hola-mundo

Is there a simple solution to this in GatsbyJS or is it more complicated?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to our problem. I have created a `.json` file with the original path and the one I want to change. For example: `/es/contact/": "/es/contacto`.

I create this file manually, and I add a path for each page that I want to change the path. Then, in the `gataby-node` file, I create the `oncreatepage` api (there is documentation for this api). In this function, I take the page parameter.

`if page.path ==` to some `.json` file path, change the path to that of the `.json` file.

Comment: Are you able to provide some sample code used in the gatsby-node file?

Answer (score 0):

Thks for help. Finally i found perfect answer for my needs. gatsby-plugin-i18n-l10n have all i need for multilingual gatsby website with url translation too. I really recommend this module and I appreciate the work of the creators.

Here is link to github where you can find that plugin:

[gatsby-plugin-i18n-l10n](https://github.com/openscript-ch/gatsby-plugin-i18n-l10n)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).